# TensorFlow on Android 4.4.2 - "Fatal Exception" on app launch

Tags: android, tensorflow

I've been trying to get [this TensorFlow project](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/#7) up and running on my Galaxy S3 (Android 4.4.2, API 19).

I've successfully run the python code on my laptop with no issues.

In order to get the project to compile and copy to my phone, I've had to set the Min Sdk Version to API 19 in Android Studio. I've done this through the "Project Structure" dialog, rather than trying to mess with the Gradle code.

When I make that one change, the project compiles with only minor warnings in Android Studio, and the resulting APK copies and installs on the phone.

However, every time I try to run the app, it immediately crashes, producing this code in the debug console:

```
709-709/org.tensorflow.demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.tensorflow.demo, PID: 709
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.util.Size
at org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity.<clinit>(ClassifierActivity.java:74)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2244)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

A few GitHub threads have told me this may be related to differences in the phone camera's API between various versions, but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue. Is anyone aware of a workaround?

Comment: According to error message : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.util.Size

I guess you have to import android.util.Size somewhere its called.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems like it is complaining about `android.util.Size`, from [the docs for that](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Size.html), it appears that this class was introduced in API version 21, which explains why it doesn't work on API level 19.

It appears that you're using the Android Demo from the TensorFlow repository. If so, [according to the README](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/1f6ed06/tensorflow/examples/android#description), that requires API 21 or higher, so that demo will not work on your phone's current setup.